# How to pause inputing data with readline module in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, readline, pause

I want to pause inputing data after the first data inputed. The user should be press enter button to continue inputing data.

input0 : /* user typing */
Paused until the user press enter again
input1 : /* user typing again */

rl.question('input0 :', d0 => {

/* Should be paused */

rl.question('input1 :', d1 => {

```
/* Done */
```

})

})